# 2nd Monitor is blinking after suspend

Tags: display, dockstation

I am using a Dell Latitude Laptop with a Docking Station. Two displays are attached to it via DVI. I am only working with the external screens the laptop is shut.

Now this is a minor problem, but still pretty annoying. When I go to suspend mode (which I do quiet frequently), the displays go off and then want to login again, the second display is turning off and on every few seconds. When I detach the DVI cable at the docking station and then plug it in again, the problem disappears.

The first display works just fine. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I guess you can image, that I don't want to plug off and in the cable, every time I'm going back from suspend.

EDIT: It seems this is indeed caused by the Docking Station. Maybe there is a problem with the Linux drivers, but someone at work told me, he has similar issues with his windows machines. I have found even more display and suspend bugs since then, I think my Dell hardware just doesn't go well with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar issue running 16.04 LTS. After every un-suspend, my secondary monitor will draw blinking trails of a window dragging on top of it, looking like I'm painting with the window, but continuously flashing at odd intervals.

While this is not a permanent fix, after every un-suspend and login, I have to do two things. I must first, turn on the secondary monitor (I'm not sure why it turns off on suspend) and second, move each windows that was previously on the second monitor and place them on the primary.

The steps are (I don't think the order matters):

1) Turn on the second display.

1. pull up Ubuntu settings
2. choose Display settings module
3. choose second monitor
4. if it is off, turn it on

2) Get the applications back into view

1. select hidden application
2. press Alt+Spacebar
3. on the keyboard choose Move
4. in context menu drag mouse cursor to primary window on the far other end until the application shows

Honestly, it might be faster for you to unplug and replug the display cable, but it's a second option.

There's probably a better fix out there. I'm still looking.

Comment: either switching to tty (ALT+CTRL+F6` and `ALT+CTRL+F7` to go back) or running `xset dpms force standby`, waiting for two seconds and waking the monitors seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the very same issue almost every time I wake up my laptop from sleep. On Windows I used to unplug the laptop from the dock station and plug back after some delay. On Ubuntu I simply change primary display setting from the `Preferences > Displays` and revert after apply. That seems to fix it (until the next sleep). There are other ways, but this one seems to be the least burdensome. And having that I think one might easily come up with some one-line console command that can be then attached to a custom keyboard shortcut and invoked when needed.